Mapbox not showing style layer from GeoJSON
I don't know why, but mapbox does not display geojson polygons on the map. I add markers as symbols in the same way and everything works.
Value geoJsonSourceValue = Value.fromJson(response.body().toString()).getValue();

mapView.getMapboxMap().removeStyleSource("c-source");


if (geoJsonSourceValue != null) {
    mapView.getMapboxMap().addStyleSource("c-source", geoJsonSourceValue);
}

String layerJson = "{"
  + "\"id\": \"c-layer\","
  + "\"type\": \"line\","
  + "\"source\": \"c-source\","
  + "\"layout\": {"
  + "}"
  + "}";


Value layerValue = Value.fromJson(layerJson).getValue();

if (layerValue != null) {
    mapView.getMapboxMap().addStyleLayer(layerValue, null);
}

